# Spark data Skew repartition with renamed key

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading an interesting article about data skewness in a Spark Join. There is an example where the joined column is renamed in both data sets and the a join invoked. The author claims that this works but I don't see why it would work versus the previous example where the join was performed without renaming. The article is [The art of joining in Spark](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-art-of-joining-in-spark-dcbd33d693c).

The relevant code from the article is this:

```
// The following row avoids the broadcasting, the dimension_table2 is very small
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold",-1)

// I'm using caching to simplify the DAG
dimension_table2.cache
dimension_table2.count

// One way to use the same partitioner is to partition on a column with the same name,
// let's rename the columns that we want to join
fact_table = fact_table.withColumnRenamed("dimension_2_key", "repartition_id")
dimension_table2 = dimension_table2.withColumnRenamed("id", "repartition_id")

fact_table = fact_table.repartition(400, fact_table.col("repartition_id"))

fact_table = fact_table.join(dimension_table2.repartition(400, dimension_table2.col("repartition_id")), 
                fact_table.col("repartition_id") === dimension_table2.col("repartition_id"), "left")
fact_table.count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article I mentioned above is not correct. I did not see any differences running with the renamed column.